# Get unique datetime string value from array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to loop over an array of arrays structure in order to filter out the duplicate datetime string values, and push the unique datetime string values sorted in a new array. I have tried to use a nested `forEach()` method in order to compare each current key value with all the key values inside the array `arr`, and push them inside the `res` array in case of non matching situation, but it seems not working properly.

**Here the array of arrays structure**

```
arr =[
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1]
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1]
];
```

**What I want to obtain as result**

```
res = ["2016-11-23 18:01",
       "2016-11-23 18:11", 
       "2016-11-23 18:22",
       "2016-11-23 18:23",
       "2016-11-23 18:24",
       "2016-11-23 18:25",
       "2016-11-23 18:26",
       "2016-11-23 18:27"];
```

Can someone give me some tips on order to understand how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would map the array of arrays to just an array of date strings:

```
arr = arrayOfArrays.map(x => x[1])
```

then if you convert it to [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you get unique values

```
var set = new Set(arr)
```

if needed you can eventually turn it back to array

```
var uniq = Array.from(set)
```

for sorting

```
uniq.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a) - new Date(b))
```

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1],
];

var arr = arrayOfArrays.map(x => x[1])
var set = new Set(arr)

var uniq = Array.from(set)

uniq.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a) - new Date(b))

console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: In this specific circumstance what `a` and `b` stand for in the .sort() method? Since in the moz documentation it refers to 2 parameter values to compare with. I have tried to `console.log` the result of datetime differences and I didn't exactly get the point.

Comment: a and b represent two elements of the array, if the function returns something below 0 a is ordered before b, otherwise after

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

### A solution using `map` and `Set`

You can map over the array to pluck the dates:

```
const dates = arr.map(item => item[1]);
```

then you can put them in a `new Set` which is an array that holds only unique items. calling `.values` on the created set will return its results.

```js
arr = [
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1],
   ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1],
];


const dates = arr.map(item => item[1]);
const result = new Set(dates);

console.log('result: ', Array.from(result))
```

### Learn more!

You can read more about sets [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Here is an image to better conceptualize the idea of the "functional style" `map/filter/reduce` array functions *(filter is where you'd ommit the onions)*:

[image]

> Image Source: https://twitter.com/francesc/status/507942534388011008

Answer (score 1):

I just want to answer with the helper of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4). I just believe this is still relevant.

```
var arr =[
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1],
    ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1]
];

_.map(_.sortBy(_.uniqBy(arr, v => v[1]), v => v[1]), v => v[1]);
```

Comment: Interesting library.. I'll take a look! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        var arr = arr = [
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1],
        ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1],
     ];
    var dates = arr.map(x => x[1])
    var uniqueArray = dates.filter(function (item, pos) {
        return dates.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get your desired output.

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var arr =[
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:11", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 2],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:01", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:22", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:23", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:25", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:24", 3],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:26", 1],
  ["some_value", "2016-11-23 18:27", 1]
];

var rest = [];


arr.forEach(function(entry) {

rest.push(entry[1]) 
});

rest.sort();

var finalArr = rest.filter( onlyUnique );

console.log(finalArr);
```